# Extract only specific texts from a txt file via python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a text file that has the following variables along with their values.

```
COM 0.95958  eh 26.9817  ehc 26.9817  ehoff    0  ew 0.181982  ewoff -0.00400919  oeh 429.788  sp_icr 15.3199  sp_il -11.4382  sp_pdelay -1.53578e-09  sp_pk_icr 15.0735  sp_pk_icr_f 7.81609e+09  sp_pk_il -12.2937  sp_pk_il_f 7.71614e+09  sp_pk_ild 3.05223  sp_pk_ild_f 7.3963e+08  sp_pk_rxrl -0.0909508  sp_pk_rxrl_f 3.01849e+09  sp_pk_txrl -6.33623  sp_pk_txrl_f 6.5967e+08  sp_rxrl -0.187543  sp_txrl -19.2629
```

How do I extract only specific variables and their corresponding values? How do I extract say **COM and its value** as well as **ehc and its value**?

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.log')):
with open(filename, 'rt') as in_file:
    str = in_file.readline()
```

How do I proceed after reading each line? 
I know that I can use substrings and extract only the needed text but is there another way I could do it?

Comment: Is everything in a single line, or separated by \n, or \t?
Furthermore, how would you like to extract the values...as tuples? as separate variables?

Comment: They're all in a single line. which would  be better? I need to dump these values that I extract into an excel sheet, delimited by a comma, after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the string in the file is repeated pattern of "ascii name followed by float-like numerics", separated by spaces. Therefore, it is convenient to use regex to parse the string.

```
import re

s = "COM 0.95958  eh 26.9817  ehc 26.9817  ehoff    0  ew 0.181982  ewoff -0.00400919  oeh 429.788  sp_icr 15.3199  sp_il -11.4382  sp_pdelay -1.53578e-09  sp_pk_icr 15.0735  sp_pk_icr_f 7.81609e+09  sp_pk_il -12.2937  sp_pk_il_f 7.71614e+09  sp_pk_ild 3.05223  sp_pk_ild_f 7.3963e+08  sp_pk_rxrl -0.0909508  sp_pk_rxrl_f 3.01849e+09  sp_pk_txrl -6.33623  sp_pk_txrl_f 6.5967e+08  sp_rxrl -0.187543  sp_txrl -19.2629 "
r = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s+(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')       # into 2 groups

d = dict(r.findall(s))
print(d)                   # {'sp_pk_icr_f': '7.81609', 'COM': '0.95958', ...
print(d['COM'])            # 0.95958 (but it is str)
print(float(d['COM']))     # 0.95958
```

I didn't convert float-like string to float. If you need it just `try: float(d[key])`

- If the file has multiple lines but the properties hold, replace all NEWLINE as in `s = open(FILE_NAME).read().replace('\n', '')`.
- If "variable name" implies non-numeric beginning letter, replace regex part for variable name with `([a-zA-Z]\w*)`

If there is multiple files and you want to keep all the mappings together, simply update the dict.

```
d = {}
for fn in filenames:
    s = open(fn, 'r').read()
    d.update(r.findall(s))
```

Now d has var-value pairs from all files.

Comment: thanks! How would I modify this if I have to read the same from 10 files in a folder?

Comment: Is it ok if I could contact you in a chat or so? I have a few other doubts regarding this?

Comment: @Potato seems no chat system here? you may still comment if it is related

Comment: There's a chat system. Let me just create one :)

Comment: @Potato no problem

Comment: If I comment a little more then it will prompt for a chat system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169845/discussion-between-potato-and-blownhither-ma).

Comment: Hey if you're there could you help me out with something similar to this question? I'll open a chat if you can help me!